# Javascript background color change upon input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to figure out a way to change the background color on my site upon user input on my form. I am not a great javascript shark but I am ok at using HTML and CSS. I am using getbootstrap.com.

Bootstrap includes validation styles for error, warning, and success states on form controls. Any .control-label, .form-control, and .help-block within that element will receive the validation styles. I would like to use the succes validation style no matter what input the user makes as long as there is an input.

I thought about using a script like the one under here but I can't figure out how to use the bootstrap validation style:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function {
  document.getElementById(elementID).MyFormIdName=MyBootstrapValidationStyleClassName;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change class than you can do

```
     document.getElementById('element_id').className='your_class_name';
```

Comment: This will replace the entire classes.  So use `+=` operator if OP has to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var target = document.getElementById('elementID');
target.className  += "MyBootstrapValidationStyleClassName";
```

**FYI:** You're missing the function name.

Is something below you're trying to do

```
<input type="text" id="inp" onblur="fun(this)" />
```

*CSS:*

```
.success {
    background: green;
}
.error {
    background: red;
}
```

*JS:*

```
function fun(inp) {
    var target = document.getElementById(inp.id);
    target.className = inp.value;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpL3g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the classes applied and apply your class only, the use the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
         document.getElementById("elementID").className="MyBootstrapValidationStyleClassName";
    })();
</script>
```

If you want don't want to remove already applied class and apply one more class, then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
         document.getElementById("elementID").className+="MyBootstrapValidationStyleClassName";
         //Or
         //$("#elementID").addClass("MyBootstrapValidationStyleClassName");
    })();
</script>
```